# How to create values folder for different screen sizes in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I want to create different values folder for different screen sizes, reason for doing this: in smaller screen text sizes are too big and pushed to new line.

so want to add following folders

res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml

but my current project values folder already has files in it. so if I create the above folders, and have dimens.xml in each folders.

Could you please suggest in which folder should the other files which are in the current Values folder go into.

[image]

Thanks in advance, please suggest,
R

Comment: Make sure you are in project view and not Android view - then you'll be able to see the folder structure better https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectView. I suspect there is no problem at all

Comment: you can read more about qualifiers here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources as for the "default" values folder it will be used if no folder with close enough qualifiers for the device exists. "Android selects the version of each resource that best matches the current device, by comparing the device configuration information with the qualifiers in the resource directory name"

Answer (score 0):

You should move the file

```
res/dimens.xml
```

into

```
res/values/dimens.xml
```

This file should contain default values.

Then create the files containing the dimensions that should be applied to specific screen sizes:

```
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml 
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml 
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml 
res/values-xxxhdpi/dimens.xml
```

You can apply this behavior to other files, such as `integers.xml` and `colors.xml`